# How to understand the "markup language to define features" in context.pbtxt

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

I am studying the context.pbtxt usage of SyntaxNet, and I have a question.

I want to define my self features of tagger and parser in the context.pbtxt file,

but I can not find any tutorial or document to explain how to use the markup

language to define features in context.pbtxt file.

For example, could any one explain the following program to me:

```
stack(3).word stack(2).word stack(1).word stack.word input.word input(1).word input(2).word input(3).word;input.digit input.hyphen;stack.suffix(length=2) input.suffix(length=2) input(1).suffix(length=2);stack.prefix(length=2) input.prefix(length=2) input(1).prefix(length=2)
```

Could some one give me a hint to learn the features define?